# How to fix Windows XP from muting sounds on every startup?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio

This started to happen few days ago: Every time I start up my computer, the global sound volume ("Playback") is set to muted (from the checkbox), in the sound control panel. So I have to open the control panel every time i start up my computer, and click that checkbox.

I have got this bug before, long time ago. I have no idea why is this happening.

Any ideas how to fix this or what is causing it?

I have SP 3 and most updates installed a half year ago or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a virus that came from flash security hole. using exe "stdrt.exe", downloading random youtube videos.

It can be removed somehow (search google), but I didnt bother trying, instead I just did reinstall which was probably faster anyways.

See: [Why is my Windows XP not allowing me to turn on sounds?](https://superuser.com/questions/412665/why-is-my-windows-xp-not-allowing-me-to-turn-on-sounds)