# Why is my Windows XP not allowing me to turn on sounds?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio

This started to happen few weeks ago: Every time I start up Windows, the global sound volume is set to muted. I was able to just click the muted button to un-muted and that was fine, until now: Now I cant even click that unmute button! Every time I click the unmute button, I hear a split of a second the music I play, then it stops immediately. It is maybe 10 milliseconds until it mutes it again.

**Edit:** It seems like its a virus came from flash security hole few weeks ago, using exe "stdrt.exe", i used sharkwire to see whats happening when i noticed my download speed was steady 300kB/s when i didnt download anything, i noticed my computer is automatically requesting youtube videos. I also noticed that when i clicked the unmute button, i could hear some song playing, at least thats what i thought from the milliseconds i heard. Then i googled and someone said his computer was playing music automatically and he also had this same exe! I have no clue what is the point of this virus, i hope its not a keylogger too... Well, i will just reinstall Windows XP and be done with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a virus that came from flash security hole. using exe "stdrt.exe", downloading random youtube videos.

It can be removed somehow (search google), but I didnt bother trying, instead I just did reinstall which was probably faster anyways.